# How do I build for iOS 4.0 devices with XCode 4 + base SDK 4.3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am trying to build my iOS project for an iPhone 4.0.1 device using Xcode 4 and base SDK 4.3. In my target's settings, I have set the Base SDK to 4.3 and an iOS deployment target of 4.0.

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
 Error: failed to locate ResourceRules.plist in '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/ResourceRules.plist' or '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/ResourceRules.plist
```

When I change the deployment target to 4.3, everything builds fine as expected, but of course I can't run this on my connected 4.0.1 device.

So what's the secret here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might have to (in iTunes) reclick the 'use this device for development' which regenerates that resources file...but that might have been for a different issue

Comment: @Robot that button is in Xcode, not iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, click on your Project in the file browser, then click on your `TARGET`'s name. Next, go to **`Build Settings`** and search for *Code Signing Resource Rules Path*. In Xcode 4, you can drag the ResourceRules.plist into this field. *see highlited section in screenshot below:*

[image]